# Putting content:encoded in RSS feed using ROME

Tags: java, rss, rome

I'm trying to put some HTML content inside `<content:encoded>` tags using ROME and its [modules](https://rometools.jira.com/wiki/display/MODULES/Home). So far I've succesfully put mediaRSS and geoRSS in the feed, but my content is not showing up.

Here's my code:

```
ContentModule contentModule = new ContentModuleImpl();
List<ContentItem> contents = new ArrayList<ContentItem>();
List<String> contentValueDOM = new ArrayList<String>();
ContentItem content = new ContentItem();

content.setContentValue("<p>Some text here</p>");
content.setContentEncoding("text/html");
content.setContentAbout("Paragraph");
content.setContentValueDOM(contentValueDOM);
contents.add(content);

contentModule.setContents(contents);
contentModule.setContentItems(contents);
entry.getModules().add(contentModule);
```

And here is my output

```
<item>
  <title>Example page</title>

  <link>http://www.example.com/news/2012/march/example-page.html</link>
  <description>Introduction</description>
  <category>news</category>
  <pubDate>Tue, 27 Mar 2012 08:18:52 GMT</pubDate>
  <guid>http://www.example.com/news/2012/march/example-page.html</guid>
  <dc:date>2012-03-27T08:18:52Z</dc:date>

  <content:items>
    <rdf:Bag>
      <rdf:li>
        <content:item rdf:about="Paragraph">
          <content:encoding rdf:resource="text/html" />
          <rdf:value />
        </content:item>
      </rdf:li>
    </rdf:Bag>

  </content:items>
  <geo:lat>52.09161879618039</geo:lat>
  <geo:long>5.1141280958007655</geo:long>
  <media:content medium="image" fileSize="16029" height="500" type="image/jpeg" width="399" url="http://www.example.com/binaries/content/gallery/image.jpg">
    <media:description type="plain/text" />
    <media:thumbnail url="http://www.example.com/binaries/content/gallery/thumbnail/image.jpg" />
  </media:content>
  <media:content medium="video" expression="full" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" isDefault="true" url="http://www.youtube.com/v/jQq4ju-vupY?rel=0">

    <media:player url="http://www.youtube.com/v/jQq4ju-vupY?rel=0&amp;feature=youtube_gdata_player" width="520" height="390" />
  </media:content>
</item>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
List<String> contents = new ArrayList<String>();
contents.add("<p>Some text here</p>");
ContentModule module = new ContentModuleImpl();
module.setEncodeds(contents);        
entry.getModules().add(module);
```

However the above outputs the feed using the [*Updated Syntax*](http://web.resource.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/#syntax2) rather than the [*Original Syntax*](http://web.resource.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/#syntax).  With the *Updated Syntax* you get something that looks like (this contains the **<content:encoded>** tag):

```
<item>
  <content:encoded><![CDATA[<p>Some text here</p>]]></content:encoded>
</item>
```

When I tried to use the **ContentItem** which does support Original Syntax (using modules-0.3.2) like you did I found that the **ContentModuleGenerator** required that ***setContentValueDOM*** contains the value of the content to output.  It also appears that this content needs to be *castable* to **org.jdom.Content** (e.g. you need to call *setContentValueDOM(List<org.jdom.Content>)*).  As **org.jdom.CDATA** is a subclass of **org.jdom.Content** you can do something like this:

```
ContentModule contentModule = new ContentModuleImpl();                
List<ContentItem> contents = new ArrayList<ContentItem>();
List<Content> contentValueDOM = new ArrayList<Content>();        
String value = "<p>Some text here</p>";
ContentItem content = new ContentItem();
content.setContentValue(value);
content.setContentAbout("Paragraph"); 
content.setContentFormat("http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/");
CDATA valueElement = new CDATA(value);
contentValueDOM.add(valueElement);
content.setContentValueDOM(contentValueDOM);      
contents.add(content);
contentModule.setContents(contents);
contentModule.setContentItems(contents);
entry.getModules().add(contentModule);
```

which produces:

```
<item>
  <title>Example page</title>
  <content:items>
    <rdf:Bag>
      <rdf:li>
        <content:item rdf:about="Paragraph">
          <content:format rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/" />
          <rdf:value><![CDATA[<p>Some text here</p>]]></rdf:value>
        </content:item>
      </rdf:li>
    </rdf:Bag>
  </content:items>
</item>
```

If you alter the above code sample replacing the CDATA section with an Element and adding appropriate format and encoding information thus:

```
//content.setContentFormat("http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/");
//CDATA valueElement = new CDATA(value);
content.setContentFormat("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml");
content.setContentEncoding("http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml#dt-wellformed");
Element valueElement = new Element("p");
valueElement.setText("Some text here");
```

you will end up with XML showing the **<content:encoding>** tag:

```
<item>
  <title>Example page</title>
  <content:items>
    <rdf:Bag>
      <rdf:li>
        <content:item rdf:about="Paragraph">
          <content:format rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" />
          <content:encoding rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml#dt-wellformed" />
          <rdf:value>
            <p>Some text here</p>
          </rdf:value>
        </content:item>
      </rdf:li>
    </rdf:Bag>
  </content:items>
</item>
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. Worked perfectly!