# Java ROME RSS library and HTML code in RSS description field

Tags: java, rss, rome

I need to include HTML code into my RSS feed. I use Java ROME RSS library:

```
SyndFeed feed = new SyndFeedImpl();
feed.setFeedType("rss_2.0");

feed.setTitle("Title");
feed.setLink("example.com");
feed.setDescription("Description");

List<SyndEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();

SyndEntryImpl entry = new SyndEntryImpl();
entry.setTitle("Name");

SyndContent syndContent = new SyndContentImpl();
syndContent.setType("text/html");
syndContent.setValue("<p>Hello, World !</p>");

entry.setDescription(syndContent);

entries.add(entry);

feed.setEntries(entries);

Writer writer = new FileWriter("rss.xml");
SyndFeedOutput output = new SyndFeedOutput();
output.output(feed, writer);
writer.close();
```

but the output XML contains encoded description:

```xml
<description>&lt;p&gt;Hello, World !&lt;/p&gt;</description>
```

How to properly include unencoded HTML code with ROME?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Analysis

According to the [RSS Best Practices Profile: 4.1.1.20.4 description](http://www.rssboard.org/rss-profile#element-channel-item-description):

> The description must be suitable for presentation as HTML. HTML markup must be encoded as character data either by employing the HTML entities `&lt;` (`"<"`) and `&gt;` (`">"`) or a `CDATA` section.

Therefore, the current output is correct.

## `CDATA` encoding

If it is desirable to have `CDATA` section (`CDATA` encoding), the following piece of code may be used:

```
final List<String> contents = new ArrayList<>();
contents.add("<p>HTML content is here!</p>");

final ContentModule module = new ContentModuleImpl();
module.setEncodeds(contents);

entry.getModules().add(module);
```

## Additional references

1. [RSS Best Practices Profile](http://www.rssboard.org/rss-profile).
2. [Putting content:encoded in RSS feed using ROME - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9887432/putting-contentencoded-in-rss-feed-using-rome).
3. [Re: CDATA Support - Mark Woodman - net.java.dev.rome.dev - MarkMail](http://markmail.org/message/lzh7oj5cfkxh7utr).
4. [rome-modules/ContentModuleImplTest.java at master · rometools/rome-modules · GitHub](https://github.com/rometools/rome-modules/blob/master/src/test/java/com/rometools/modules/content/ContentModuleImplTest.java).

## `description` versus `content:encoded`

> Should I use both - `description` and `content:encoded` nodes or only one of them in my RSS feed item ?
>
> And how about [the following](https://cyber.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html#hrelementsOfLtitemgt)?
>
> > An item may also be complete in itself, if so, the description contains the text (entity-encoded HTML is allowed; see examples), <…>

According to the RSS 2.0 specification, using the `description` element is enough: exactly as you have quoted. Here are the examples: [Encoding & item-level descriptions (RSS 2.0 at Harvard Law)](https://cyber.harvard.edu/rss/encodingDescriptions.html).

For additional details please refer to the question: [Difference between description and content:encoded tags in RSS2 - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220670/difference-between-description-and-contentencoded-tags-in-rss2).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Should I use both - description and content:encoded nodes or only one of them in my RSS feed item ?

Comment: And how about the following: https://cyber.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html#hrelementsOfLtitemgt - `An item may also be complete in itself, if so, the description contains the text (entity-encoded HTML is allowed; see examples)` ?

Comment: @alexanoid, thank you for the questions! Please see the updated answer.

Comment: is there any chance with ROME library in include CDATA section into description field? If so, could you please also show an example.

Comment: @alexanoid, have you tried the example provided in the «CDATA encoding» section of the answer?

Comment: Yes, it is adding new node with the name `<content:encoded>` to the output RSS XML, but I'm interested to have CDATA exactly in the `<description>` node

Comment: @alexanoid, right. I can only share these references with you: [the comment on CDATA sections being escaped · Issue #280 · rometools/rome · GitHub](https://github.com/rometools/rome/issues/280#issuecomment-276796534) and [Putting content:encoded in RSS feed using ROME - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9887432/putting-contentencoded-in-rss-feed-using-rome).

Comment: @alexanoid, you are welcome! Hope, that information has helped.